# Ajax using Gson

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I want to get the `json` object from the `success` of an `ajax` this is what i've done so far

My dropdown list

```
<select id="testers_team" class="tester_team">
    <optgroup label="Current Value">
        <option><c:out value="${info.team}"></c:out></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Teams">
        <c:forEach var="team" items="${requestScope.testers}">
            <option value="${team.key}">${team.key}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This one is my `Ajax`, the `select` above is iterated by a loop so i have to use each to know which drop down i'm working with ( just to inform you guys )

```
$('.tester_team').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function() {

          $.ajax({
         url: 'Analysis',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {team: $(this).val()},
         success: function(data){
             alert(data); // alert not working

         }
          });

    }); 
});
```

I'm using `Gson` on my servlet heres the code:

```
String team = request.getParameter( "team" );
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> testerList
              = new UsersDAO().getTestersOfAllTeams();
ArrayList<String> testers = testerList.get( team );

if( testers != null )
{
    response.setContentType( "application/json" );
    response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    try
    {
        response.getWriter().write( new Gson().toJson( testers ) );
        //this one is printing so that means it actually succeed to parse?
        System.out.println( team );
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
       // just want to test out if it really failed
       System.out.println( "failed" ); 
       log.debug( "Unable to get parse request", e );
    }
}
```

The problem is in the script with `Ajax` doesn't trigger the `alert(data);` function when i change the drop down list what is the problem with my code? or am I misusing the codes?

Comment: You are printing values to console, you have to print a json response with PrinterWriter inside the Servlet. Can you post all the servlet code to validate servlet calling? If is not printing maybe it has errors

Comment: There is no stack-trace whenever I run the codes, and i already post all the servlet post code that is related to the problem. Don't worry about the HashMap, it is not null. The `println` already prove it to me. About the PrintWriter I'm not planning to write `html` code from the servlet if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, alright i found the answer change the code from the servlet:

```
if( testers != null )
{
    response.setContentType( "application/json" );
    response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    try
    {
        response.getWriter().write( new Gson().toJson( testers ) );
        //this one is printing so that means it actually succeed to parse?
        System.out.println( team );
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
       // just want to test out if it really failed
       System.out.println( "failed" ); 
       log.debug( "Unable to get parse request", e );
    }
}
```

to

```
if( testers != null )
{
    response.setContentType( "application/json" );
    response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    try
    {
        response.getWriter().write( new Gson().toJson( testers ) );
        //this one is printing so that means it actually succeed to parse?
        System.out.println( team );
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
       // just want to test out if it really failed
       System.out.println( "failed" ); 
       log.debug( "Unable to get parse request", e );
    }
    return;
}
```

I just added `return;`

Answer (score 0):

The success callback function seems to be failing to parse the JSON result.

Try passing a value to your servlet as a URL query string like `http://localhost/project/Analysis?team=some-value-you-know`

Then validate the printed JSON using a tool like [http://jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)", fix the JSON you're generating [probably double quotations around the JSON object keys].

Also try using the Developer Tools's JavaScript console in your browser, it will help you with the JavaScript errors.

Hope this helps, 
Shareb.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But about the validate tool you mention, How would I use this site? I'm actually a newbie to web-development.

Comment: Just paste the generated JSON object into the tool's text area, click validate and check the results, if it's not valid you'll get a parsing error.
Also you can click on FAQ to get more info about the error and suggestions on how to solve it.